# What are the possible reason of WordPress database error: [Query was empty]?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have run into error below but it seems like I can't get proper error logs.

> WordPress database error Query was empty for query  made by

I had this codes that will throw almost similar to the error above.

```
$query_select = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare(
    " % "
    , 1
),ARRAY_A);
```

My question is, what are the possible codes that will throw `query was empty` like in my above code.

Comment: Any time there is a [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: This is a horrible question that should have been closed. Adding a bounty on  a horrible question does not make it a better question

Comment: Try to completely deleting the plugin and removing all the wp_support_* database tables, then reinstalling and activating them again.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I added a bounty because no one has answered it.

Answer (score 1):

There are some of the possible ways to get these type of error. The below usage may or may not be useful to you.

Using the $wpdb Object

**1st Method** - Declaring $wpdb as global and using it to execute an SQL query statement that returns a PHP object

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

**2nd Method** - Utilizing the $GLOBALS superglobal. Does not require global keyword ( but may not be best practice )

```
$results = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_options
                                            WHERE option_id = 1', OBJECT );
```

Some users asked these type of question in stack exchange link below
[To refer:](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64648/why-am-i-getting-this-error-wordpress-database-error-query-was-empty)

[Another link to refer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 1):

The `$wpdb->prepare` method performs this functionality for WordPress, which supports both a sprintf()-like and vsprintf()-like syntax.

The %s (string), %d (integer) and %f (float) formats are supported.

All % characters inside SQL string literals, including LIKE wildcards, must be double-% escaped as %%.

So if we debug your code we like this:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare(" % ", 1);
die( var_dump($sql) );
```

The result will be: `string ' ' (length=1)`

OMG an empty string! So that's why we see the `query was empty` error.

The prepare method is expecting the format string to contain any of the following; `%d`, `%s`, or `%f`. So if you want your SQL query to be `1` you would need to change you code to:

```
$query_select = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('%d', 1), ARRAY_A );
```

Or if you want your SQL to be `%` you would need escape it with another `%` like this:

```
$query_select = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare('%%', 1), ARRAY_A );
```

You can find out more about the prepare method and placeholders here [Class Reference/wpdb « WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

When we execute wp db query it's change properties in last query.
I am not understand your question but following below code if this helpful for you.

```
global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare(" % " , 1 ) );
   if( $wpdb->last_error ){
    //print_r( $wpdb->dbh)   
    $dbh = $wpdb->dbh;
    echo $dbh->errno;  // if no == 1065 then query was empty
    echo $dbh->error; // Query was empty          
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb
see the examples.
Prepare must have a valid sql query with placeholders for variables you want in your query:

```
$wpdb->prepare( 
"
    SELECT sum(meta_value) 
    FROM $wpdb->postmeta //valid sql statements here
    WHERE meta_key = %s
", 
$meta_key)
```

meanwhile your code does nothing:

```
$wpdb->prepare(
" % " //no sql statements here
, 1 ...)
```

it looks like you wanted to

```
select * from someTable where someField % 1 -- (it will return no rows)
```

so, any empty query will return this error.